# Is $\prod^t_i S_{N_i} \wr D_{m_i}$ a normal subgroup of $S_{\sum^t_i N_i m_i}$?

Tags: symmetric-groups, normal-subgroups, group-homomorphism, dihedral-groups, wreath-product

How can I determine whether $\prod^t_i S_{N_i} \wr D_{m_i}$ a normal subgroup of $S_{\sum^t_i N_i m_i}$?

Here, $i, N_i, m_i$ are positive integers, $S_{N_i}$ is the symmetric group over $N_i$ symbols, $D_{m_i}$ is the dihedral group of order $2 m_i$.

**My effort:**

I understand that there are [more than one ways](http://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Proving_that_a_subgroup_is_normal) to determine this without checking all group elements.

**Construct a homomorphism having it as kernel**

Here we have to construct a homomorphism $\varphi: S_{\sum^t_i N_i m_i} \to K$ such that the kernel of the homomorphism is precisely $\prod^t_i S_{N_i} \wr D_{m_i}$. How can I do that?

**Compute its commutator with the whole group**

How can I check if $[S_{\sum^t_i N_i m_i}, \prod^t_i S_{N_i} \wr D_{m_i}]$ is contained in $\prod^t_i S_{N_i} \wr D_{m_i}$ ?

Comment: I am not sure if I understand everything in the question but if $X:=\sum_i^tN_im_i$ and $S_X$ is a symmetric group you know that the only normal subgroups of it are the trivial one, $S_X$ and $A_X$ (the alternating group) except if $X=4$. In other words, your group $G$ is normal in $S_X$ and provided $X\neq 4$ if and only if its cardinal is $1$ $|S_X|$ or $|S_X|/2$.

Comment: No normal subgroup of a symmetric group is a product of subgroups in a non-trivial way (when the degree is at least $5$).